# Error:The value of attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: android

I am a novice trying to figure out the error. But I have reached upon no solution even after trying it several times.

I am sharing the android-manifest.xml file code. More details are after this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.home.timestopper" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".StopwatchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.applozic.application.key"
            android:value="API_KEY" /> <!-- Applozic Application Key -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.notification.icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/mobicom_ic_launcher" />  <!-- Launcher Icon -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.notification.smallIcon"
            android:resource="YOUR_LAUNCHER_SMALL_ICON" /> <!-- Launcher white Icon -->

        <meta-data android:name="share_text"
            android:value="Talk about time!..the essence of life." />  <!-- Invite Message -->

        <meta-data android:name="main_folder_name"
            android:value="@string/default_media_location_folder" /> <!-- Attachment Folder Name -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="GEO_KEY" />  <!--Replace with your geo api key from google developer console  -->
        <!-- For testing purpose use 
        To disable the location sharing via map add this line ApplozicSetting.getInstance(context).disableLocationSharingViaMap(); in onSuccess of Applozic UserLoginTask -->

        <meta-data android:name="activity.open.on.notification"
            android:value="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity" /> <!-- NOTE : Do NOT change this value -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.package.name"
            android:value="${applicationId}" /> <!-- NOTE: Do NOT change this, it should remain same i.e 'com.package.name' -->



        <receiver android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.notification.MTNotificationBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.send.notification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>




        <activity android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".StopwatchActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplozicTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".StopwatchActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.people.activity.MobiComKitPeopleActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/activity_contacts_list"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Applozic.People.Theme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable_contacts" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.FullScreenImageActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="Image"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Applozic_FullScreen_Theme">
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ContactSelectionActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplozicTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ChannelCreateActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplozicTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ChannelNameActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplozicTheme">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ChannelInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplozicTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.MobiComAttachmentSelectorActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplozicTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.MobicomLocationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:parentActivityName="com.applozic.mobicomkit.uiwidgets.conversation.activity.ConversationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplozicTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>


        <service android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.api.conversation.MessageIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />

        <service android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.api.conversation.ApplozicIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.api.conversation.ApplozicMqttIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.broadcast.TimeChangeBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.applozic.mobicomkit.broadcast.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="<APP_PKG_NAME>" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".pushnotification.ApplozicGcmListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".pushnotification.GcmInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.home.timestopper.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.home.timestopper.pushnotification.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.home.timestopper.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.home.timestopper.pushnotification.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />



    </manifest>
```

So, what I am trying to do here is to integrate a chat feature in a small time-stopper app that I just created for the learning purpose and I am integrating it also for the learning purpose.

When I build gradle,Result shows *Error:The value of attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.*

and

*Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\APnaturals\AndroidStudioProjects\TimeStopper\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml*

When I replace APP_PKG_NAME with the one mentioned in here

> manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       package="com.example.home.timestopper"

Gradle Build fails again without giving any cause.

Comment: Post your whole Manifest file

Comment: this is the whole manifest file.maybe its out of order. I will correct that.

Comment: You missed to replace  package name  in receiver com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver    i.e                                 <category android:name="<APP_PKG_NAME>" /> with  <category android:name="com.example.home.timestopper" />

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>  <category android:name="<APP_PKG_NAME>" />
> ```

Looks like you forgot to configure your package name in this element.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Interesting part is that error is only on my machine, not on my friend's machine. :/

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `APP_PKG_NAME` from metadata and put your package name or ID, as in **androidmanifest.xml** not allow `<>`.